# Install & Activate Plugin with one click on button

Tags: wordpress, plugins, installation

Iam developing new theme and need to add button notice to install the required plugin but need this button to install & activate in one time and for sure if the plugin install the button will activate only, please advice(the required plugin only one not a lot of plugins)

I expect the out put of click button two actions install and activate required plugin

Answer (score 0):

Most of the themes use TGMPA to require plugins installation and activation, this is the best solution.

check here: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/download/

Comment: Thank you :) But I want to add custom function to do that in one click, Don't want to use TGM Plugin.